# Flow error on function added to prototype

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

we have a ton of components and many of them call a "register" function that, in turn, adds a method to the component's prototype.  It has to do with translations.  The method is simply 't(name:string):string'.  It works great at runtime, but flow gives an error, such as `<Button title={this.t('signIn')} /> property`t`. Property not found in class Welcome extends Component {`

I get it, flow is a static type checker and that method is dynamically added.  I'd rather not make a new class with a single function that all components have to derive from in order to satisfy flow.

What I'd like to be able to do is say "Flow, class Component from module React also has a 't' function".  I tried messing with declare interface/module/class/function, but nothing fixed it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not simply import `t` at the top of the file? Why does it need to be a part of the class?

Comment: Importing 't' as a module won't help because t is an instance function on the class.  The idea was to quiet Flow without having to modify a bunch of files.  But it looks like the best approach for me is to just sub Component and have that be a common base class.  No big deal, just not what I wanted.  Flow is great but should allow for exceptions like this considering JS is a dynamic language

Comment: But why does it need to be an instance function on the class? Is the `t` function referencing `this`?

Comment: t is referencing the displayName of the type. I suppose I could import t with the component type as an argument.  Maybe I'll give that a shot.  Point still is, is that use case possible.